# Deck of cards that deals a number of cards to a number of players

Tags: ruby, oop

I built a deck of cards:

```
class Card
  attr_accessor :rank, :suit

  def initialize(rank, suit)
    @rank = rank
    @suit = suit
  end

  def output_card
    puts "#{self.rank} of #{self.suit}"
  end
end

class Deck
  def initialize
      @cards = []
      @ranks = ["Ace", 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
      @suits = [:hearts, :spades, :diamonds, :clubs]
      @suits.each do |suit|
        @ranks.each do |rank|
          @cards << Card.new(rank, suit)
      end
    end
  end

  def shuffle
    @cards.shuffle!
  end

  def deal
    @cards.shift
  end

  def output_deck
    @cards.each do |card|
      card.output_card
    end
  end
end

deck = Deck.new
deck.shuffle
deck.deal
deck.output_deck
puts "Show top card:"
deck.deal.output_card
```

I am struggling to add `Dealer` class to deal a specified number of cards to a specified number of players.

If anyone would explain that, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This question seems a bit homework-ish.... Be that as it may, it will help if you elaborate on what your having trouble understanding. Asking to explain OOP and how it fits in this instance is too broad. Narrow down the question, and we can try to give you a more useful answer. If you're new to OOP and you're just unsure how to ask it using that terminology, use terminology from other programming styles that you're more familiar with.

Comment: Again, I am very new to coding in general, and while this is homework per se, it is not for a grade or anything of the sort. It was merely something extra assigned by my mentor (doing an online bootcamp) and I do not have the chance to meet with him again until Friday, so I was hoping someone could help me in the meantime so I could advance on to the actual curriculum. I have very limited time with them, so I thought this would be a good place to find help. Sorry if I came off otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :name, :cards
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @cards = []
  end
end

class HoldEmPoker
  def cards_per_player
    2
  end
end

class Dealer
  def initialize(deck, game)
    @deck = deck
    @game = game
  end

  def deal_to(player)
    @game.cards_per_player.times do 
      player.cards << @deck.deal
    end
  end
end


p1 = Player.new("Negreanu")
p2 = Player.new("Ivey")
p3 = Player.new("Hellmuth")
players = [p1, p2, p3]
deck = Deck.new
deck.shuffle
game = HoldEmPoker.new
dealer = Dealer.new(deck, game)
players.each { |p| dealer.deal_to(p) }
p1.cards #=> an array with two Card objects
```

If you want, you can add a `deal` method to Dealer class

```
def deal(players)
  players.each do |player|
    @game.cards_per_player.times do 
      player.cards << @deck.deal
    end
  end
end

players = [...]
dealer.deal(players)
```